# How do I make an interactive UINavigationController transition that can pop OR push? Push animation is flipping?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to have a bit of a weird `UINavigationController` concept, where you can pop a view controller off the stack by panning back (like the iOS 7 pop gesture), but it will remember the popped view controller, allowing you to "unpop it" (push it back onto the stack) by panning the other direction. Think of it like the forward and back buttons in Safari, how if you go back, you can still go forward if you want to and bring the page back.

I've subclassed `UINavigationController` and set myself as the delegate, returning a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` object and a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` object:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    if operation == .Push {
        return Animator(presenting: true)
    } else if operation == .Pop {
        return Animator(presenting: false)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

and

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerForAnimationController animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
    if animationController is Animator {
        return interactiveTransition
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Depending if the Animator is set to be presenting or not, I call specific methods, this is for if presenting is true:

```
func presentWithTransitionContext(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let toViewControllerView = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!.view
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()

    containerView.addSubview(toViewControllerView)
    toViewControllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(containerView.bounds.width, 0.0)
    applyShadowToView(toViewControllerView)

    let animationCurve: UIViewAnimationOptions = transitionContext.isInteractive() ? .CurveLinear : .CurveEaseInOut

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), delay: 0.0, options: animationCurve, animations: {
        toViewControllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }, completion: { finished in
        return transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
    })
}
```

I override `popViewControllerAnimated` so I can save the view controller being popped:

```
override func popViewControllerAnimated(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
    poppedViewControllers.insert(visibleViewController!, atIndex: 0)
    return super.popViewControllerAnimated(animated)
}
```

I add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in the `UINavigationController` subclass' `awakeFromNib()` to its view, and it calls this method to push/pop:

```
func panned(panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let panningRight = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(view).x > 0
    let progress: CGFloat

    if panningRight {
        progress = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(view).x / view.bounds.width
    } else {
        progress = -panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(view).x / view.bounds.width
    }

    if panGestureRecognizer.state == .Began {
        interactiveTransition = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()

        if panningRight {
            popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        } else {
            let viewControllerToPush = poppedViewControllers[0]
            poppedViewControllers.removeAtIndex(0)
            pushViewController(viewControllerToPush, animated: true)
        }
    } else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .Changed {
        interactiveTransition!.updateInteractiveTransition(progress)
    } else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .Ended {
        if progress > 0.5 {
            interactiveTransition!.finishInteractiveTransition()
        } else {
            interactiveTransition!.cancelInteractiveTransition()
        }

        interactiveTransition = nil
    } else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .Cancelled {
        interactiveTransition!.cancelInteractiveTransition()
        interactiveTransition = nil
    }
}
```

However, whenever I gesture to push a previously popped view controller onto the navigation stack it animates the presentation the opposite way (the view controller being presented shows up immediately, and the current view controller slides away). I have no idea why that is though. Is it not possible to do both? Am I not removing a view when I should be?